# Can I iterate over a class in Python?

Tags: python

I have a class that keeps track of its instances in a class variable, something like this:

```
class Foo:
    by_id = {}

    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        self.by_id[id] = self
```

What I'd like to be able to do is iterate over the existing instances of the class.  I can do this with:

```
for foo in Foo.by_id.values():
    foo.do_something()
```

but it would look neater like this:

```
for foo in Foo:
    foo.do_something()
```

is this possible?  I tried defining a classmethod `__iter__`, but that didn't work.

Comment: Please show your classmethod `__iter__`, and an example of it failing.

Comment: Be aware, however, that you'll never get rid of your instances. You should work with weak references.

Comment: Fortunately, life time of instances is not an issue.  But I'd love to see how it should be done.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you want to iterate over the *class*, you have to define a metaclass which supports iteration.

x.py:

```
class it(type):
    def __iter__(self):
        # Wanna iterate over a class? Then ask that class for iterator.
        return self.classiter()

class Foo:
    __metaclass__ = it # We need that meta class...
    by_id = {} # Store the stuff here...

    def __init__(self, id): # new isntance of class
        self.id = id # do we need that?
        self.by_id[id] = self # register istance

    @classmethod
    def classiter(cls): # iterate over class by giving all instances which have been instantiated
        return iter(cls.by_id.values())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Foo(123)
    print list(Foo)
    del a
    print list(Foo)
```

As you can see in the end, deleting an instance will not have any effect on the object itself, because it stays in the `by_id` dict. You can cope with that using `weakref`s when you

```
import weakref
```

and then do

```
by_id = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()
```

. This way the values will only kept as long as there is a "strong" reference keeping it, such as `a` in this case. After `del a`, there are only weak references pointing to the object, so they can be gc'ed.

Due to the warning concerning `WeakValueDictionary()`s, I suggest to use the following:

```
[...]
    self.by_id[id] = weakref.ref(self)
[...]
@classmethod
def classiter(cls):
    # return all class instances which are still alive according to their weakref pointing to them
    return (i for i in (i() for i in cls.by_id.values()) if i is not None)
```

Looks a bit complicated, but makes sure that you get the objects and not a `weakref` object.

Comment: What about the weak references you were talking about? I wasn't quite sure what you meant, and this answer also doesn't contain anything about it

Comment: See this on weak references: http://docs.python.org/library/weakref.html#weakref.WeakValueDictionary

Comment: Nice touch, delegating iteration back to a method on the class.

Comment: @NiklasB. While normal references are stored in the `by_id` structure, they will never be garbage collected.

Comment: @Marcin: Yeah, I must have overseen the fact that they are stored inside the class, not an instance...

Comment: I know I suggested weakref.WeakValueDictionary, but note the warning. It might actually be better to store weakrefs, and dereference them in the iterator.

Comment: PEP8 recommends never inventing names with double leading and trailing underscores like `__classiter__`.

Answer (score 13):

Magic methods are always looked up on the class, so adding `__iter__` to the class won't make it iterable. However the class is an instance of its metaclass, so the metaclass is the correct place to define the `__iter__` method.

```
class FooMeta(type):
    def __iter__(self):
        return self.by_id.iteritems()

class Foo:
    __metaclass__ = FooMeta
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

You can create a list with a global scope, define a list in the main module as follows:

```
fooList = []
```

Then add:

```
class Foo:
  def __init__(self):
    fooList.append(self)
```

to the **init** of the foo class

Then everytime you create an instance of the Foo class it will be added to the fooList list.

Now all you have to do is iterate through the array of objects like this

```
for f in fooList:
    f.doSomething()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a comprehension list and then call member methods as follows:

```
  class PeopleManager:         
        def __init__(self):       
           self.People = []        
        def Add(self, person):     
           self.People.append(person) 

  class Person:                
        def __init__(self,name,age): 
           self.Name = name          
           self.Age = age   

  m = PeopleManager()
  [[t.Name,t.Age] for t in m.People]
```

call to fill the object list:

```
  m = PeopleManager()
  m.Add( Person("Andy",38))
  m.Add( Person("Brian",76))
```

Comment: You get an upvote just for the MPeople reference :D

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class list and then call append in the init method as follows:

```
class Planet:
  planets_list = []

  def __init__(self, name):
     self.name = name
     self.planets_list.append(self)
```

Usage:

```
p1 = Planet("earth")
p2 = Planet("uranus")

for i in Planet.planets_list:
    print(i.name)
```