# How self in odoo represent more than one class instance using normal traditional python class definition and iterate over them using for i in self

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, openerp-8, odoo-10

I was **confused** when I wrote my question, I felt that it was a **vague question** for some readers.
So I rewrote the question again to be clear ?

I learned object oriented programming using Java. My knowledge about **self** in python that it's like **this** in Java the two are representing the **instance  - one instance  - of the class itself**.
Ex: self.name, self.age, etc ...

So the question here, **how** Odoo framework developers made the **self represents more than one instance** of the class and **iterate over self** using **traditional normal python class definition** ?

```
for i in self
```

The answer is can't be achieved using normal python definition they do it using **meta-class** as described in **URLs in the answer** of this questions.

Comment: What is your question here ? And why do you consider the way the recordset is implemented (unordered, immutable collection) not pythonic ? What is unusual in `for record in self` ?

Comment: @GeorgeDaramouskas The question is not how to iterate over "**unordered immutable collection**", The question is how we use self as "**unordered immutable collection**" to **iterate over class instances in python**, You **can not do that using normal class** definition in python, **You have to use metaclass**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to be late for posting my answer, I found my missing

[Iterate over class instances (self) 01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814535/can-i-iterate-over-a-class-in-python)
[Iterate over class instances (self) 02](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739882/iterating-over-object-instances-of-a-given-class-in-python)
[Iterate over class instances (self) 03](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/bugs/704114)

Answer (score 0):

In the new api  when you use the decorator @.multi  odoo will call the function passing in the self a set of ids like if you check record in tree view and choose delete in the more menu odoo will pack the selected record and call the method only one time and pass all the records in a record set so self is a list you should always usel loop .
But if you use @api.one decorator self will contain only one record you cannot loop the self here. So if you select multi record in the tree view and execute some action for the selected 10 record adoo will call this function 10 time  every time with a record it'slike he loops throw the selected record and call the function it's not recommanded.
For compute fields the decorator is @api.depends it behave like the @api.multi here self is a recordset so always use loop or youwill have a error if you didn't specially with tree view.
Ihad to learn this with the hard way is used @api.depends with @api.one  on the same method in a model that contains a mellion record i used print to see the work on the console odoo called the function million time soi will never use api.one onkply if i'm sure of that

Comment: Thanks for you reply and appreciated support but this is not what I was searching for.